# Change current read-only form record to be editable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using Microsoft Access 2013 to create a database where I have a form that the default view is read-only to prevent accidental editing.  I am currently trying to include a button to enable editing for the current record only.  I tried using `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open the record in editable mode (since I am using that command elsewhere to open specific records), but it seems like it can not open a record within the same form with that command.

I thank you in advance for any advice on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit anything else than the current record.

Use this code line:

```
Me.AllowEditions = True
```

But it doesn't make much sense as you could just open the form this way.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly.  The reason I am doing this is because I am looking to use the same form for both viewing records as well as updating records.  Your recommendation had two errors, but it got me on the right rack.  I found that the correct command is `Me.Form.AllowEdits = True`

Comment: Will you need to disallow edits when you are done? I have my forms as no edits; no deletes etc. With a command button to allow when needed. At the moment I don't bother with disallowing, other than when the form is reopened. I wonder if disallowing could be instigated when the focu moves from the current record.

Comment: You can lock and unlock the controls, which has the same effect as allowing/disallowing edits.  It may be better since it gives you more control and ensures that existing records are locked until the user decides to make an edit, and this addresses Great Crosby's concern about disallowing when the focus move from the current record.

Answer (score 1):

I learned this from the first VBA book I ever read (Access 97 VBA for Dummies, I think), and I have never seen anyone use the Tag property since, which has no other purpose than for you to find something to use it for.  Enter "Lockable" in the tag property for any control (text box, combobox etc.) that you want to protect.  Add a button named btnEdit to your form.

When you enter a record, the Form Current event will unlock the controls if it is a new record, and lock the controls if it is an existing record.

The button will then unlock to allow edits, and re-lock once the record is exited.  I've found this to be very effective in preventing inadvertent edits.

```
 Private Sub Form_Current()

 Dim ctlCurr As Control
    'Lock the record if it is not new. Prevents inadvertent edits.
    If Me.NewRecord = False Then
        For Each ctlCurr In Me.Controls
            If ctlCurr.Tag = "Lockable" Then
            ctlCurr.Locked = True
            End If
            btnEdit.Enabled = True
        Next
    End If
    'Unlock a new record for editing.
    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
        For Each ctlCurr In Me.Controls
            If ctlCurr.Tag = "Lockable" Then
            ctlCurr.Locked = False
            End If
        Next
        btnEdit.Enabled = False
    End If  
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
      Dim ctlCurr As Control
        'Unlocks a record for editing.  Requires the operator to make the decision to edit.
        If Me.NewRecord = False Then
            For Each ctlCurr In Me.Controls
                If ctlCurr.Tag = "Lockable" Then
                ctlCurr.Locked = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```